# Unity VR racket doesn't interact well with ball

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I am trying swing a ball with a racket, and the interaction doesn't feel well, I can't even swing the ball as when I try to do that the ball will just go through the racket.

Here's a video that demonstrates the issue:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gYSRtmuqf6s

Here are my settings for the ball:

[image]

for the racket:

[image]

Here are my physics settings (I have already set the penetration velocity very high):

[image]

I have also set the timestamp very low

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do that with physics alone. You need to calculate velocity manually by script. The ball is probably moving to fast for unity physics, utilizing rays will help.

Comment: True. You could do your own simple physics and checking the collision with a ray between the current ball position and where the ball is expected to be moved during the current physics loop timestep. You should also do this after the racket movement has been processed for the current timestep/frame.